# What is the good approach in solving this programming challenge?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

In one programming contest, this problem was given.

A database contains a table with two columns.
First is the id of the member,
Second can be

- 0(if he doesn't have any sub-ordinates),
- id(if only one sub-ordinate),
- sum of id's(if he has two sub-ordinates)

//Max Two assistants only.

We need to **find the head of the gang**

Example Input:

The first line indicates 'n' [the number of records,`3<n<100`]
the next four are the actual records

```
4 
1 7
2 1
3 0
4 0
```

Here 3,4 has 0 in their second columns which means they don't have any sub-ordinates.

1 has 7 in the second column which is not the id of any of the member ,so it can be the sum of two id's[so 3,4 are sub-ordinates of 7]

2 has 1 as the sub-ordinate

so 2 is the head of the gang.

Output:

```
2
```

I am unable to solve the problem.
Can anyone help me?

If it is not a correct place to ask this type of question means
Can suggest me some websites where I can post these type of questions?

Comment: Hav you tried anything at all?

Comment: what defines the " head of the gang" is it some one that assists nobody? Is there only one such person?
 Is there a limit to how large the database can be or a restriction on the numbers? 
I assume you are given the Database and not trying to set up a database that would allow for the problem to be solved.

Comment: Your description of the input seems incomplete, given the sample input.  What's the first line of the input?

Comment: Yes ,I have tried but i didn't get it. 
Head is the one who isn't a sub-ordinate and is only one.
I have added some extra information. 
Now check it once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will give you a hint (which is almost a solution) here:

What is the **sum** of all the numbers in the second column?

---

Answer (spoiler alert):

> The id of the head of the gang (if exists) is: `1 + 2 + ... + n - (the sum of all the numbers in the second column)`. Note that, the above number actually gives the sum of the id's of all top-level members (i.e. members who do not have any sub-ordinates). Thus the correctness relies on the assumption that there exists one unique head of the gang.

Comment: Not an answer - should just be a comment.

Comment: @PaulR Please think about it again. It IS an answer!

Comment: Not really - it's a hint, which is useful, but it doesn't really provide an answer as such.

Comment: @PaulR Have you really understood the answer?

Comment: Of course - which is why I said it's a useful hint.

Comment: @PaulR So I edited this answer. Is this now an "answer" for you?

Comment: Sure - I think your original hint posted as a comment might have been more appropriate, but yes, it's now an answer.

Comment: @PaulR Well ... of course this problem is simple enough to be answered in the comment. But anyway ...

Comment: I've edited the answer to make the full solution a hidden "spoiler" (hover over it to reveal) - I hope that's OK ?

Comment: @PaulR Sure, that's quite good! I didn't know one could add spoilers ... thx!

Comment: Yes, it's very useful: `>!` at the start of a paragraph makes it a spoiler.

Comment: Wow..LOL ..got it :)
Thanks